# r data.table filter based on count of rows satisfying a condition

Tags: r, filter, count, data.table

I am learning data.table and got confused at one place. Need help to understand how the below can be achieved. The data I am having, I need to filter out those brands which have sales of 0 in the 1st period OR do not have sales > 0 in atleast 14 periods. I have tried and I think I have achieved the 1st part....however not able to get how I can get the second part of filtering those brands which do not have sales > 0 in atleast 14 periods.

Below is my sample data and code that I have written. Please suggest how I can I achieve the second part?

```
library(data.table)
#### set the seed value
set.seed(9901)

#### create the sample variables for creating the data
group <- sample(1:7,1200,replace = T)
brn <- sample(1:10,1200,replace = T)
period <- rep(101:116,75)
sales <- sample(0:50,1200,replace = T)

#### create the data.table
df1 <- data.table(cbind(group,brn,period,sales))

#### taking the minimum value by group x brand x period
df1_min <- df1[,.(min1 = min(sales,na.rm = T)),by = c('group','brn','period')][order(group,brn,period)]

#### creating the filter
df1_min$fil1 <- ifelse(df1_min$period == 101 & df1_min$min1 == 0,1,0)
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Could you elaborate how the group variable enters? Shall the # of period positive sales per brand be aggregated across groups prior to being evaluated against the 14-period restriction?

Comment: There are a few issues on the data on top of J.G.'s comment. Do group, brn & period compose a primary key? (there are duplicates but shall the sales be summed). Also, can the missing trios be considered to have 0 sales?

Comment: @J.G. Need to have # of periods with positive sales per brand within the group. So the aggregation has to happen at group x brand

Comment: @JonNagra We can have duplicate rows in the original data as per row is a record of sales.....so if one brand has multiple rows means that brand got sold on multiple occasions....I agree there needs to be product column as well which is missing in this case but I believe it would not hamper our aggregation

Comment: So if I understand correctly, a brn can be disqualified from one group (where #sales>0 is less than 14 periods) but kept in another (where it is >14)? Or is the brn disqualified across the board if at for any group, #sales>0 is less than 14?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, the 1st part is what I am looking for...it is by group so as you mentioned.... a brn can be disqualified from one group (where #sales>0 is less than 14 periods) but kept in another (where it is >14)?

Comment: Got it. Lastly, does the first restriction apply to the first period that sales for the group/brn pair was recorded? Not all pairs start at 101, try df1[, min(period), .(brn, group)].

Comment: @J.G. It is for the dataset wide minimum period. i.e. 101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first restriction applies on the dataset wide minimum period (101), implying that brn/group pairs starting with a 0-sales period greater than 101 are still included.

```
# 1. brn/group pairs with sales of 0 in the 1st period.
brngroup_zerosales101 = df1[sales == 0 & period == min(period), .(brn, group)]

# 2a. Identify brn/group pairs with <14 positive sale periods
df1[, posSale := ifelse(sales > 0, 1, 0)] # Was the period sale positive?

# 2b. For each brn/group pair, sum posSale and filter posSale < 14
brngroup_sub14 = df1[, .(GroupBrnPosSales = sum(posSale)), by = .(brn, group)][GroupBrnPosSales < 14, .(brn, group)]

# 3. Join the two restrictions
restr = rbindlist(list(brngroup_zerosales101, brngroup_sub14)) 

df1[, ID := paste(brn, group)] # Create a brn-group ID
restr[, ID := paste(brn, group)] # See above

filtered = df1[!(ID %in% restr[,ID]),]
```

Comment: Thank you JG. This is helps !! Only thing I had to add **fill = T** in rbindlist as, brngroup_zerosales101 is having 2 columns and brngroup_sub14 is having 3 columns.

Comment: Cheers. Fixed the column selection in brngroup_sub14.

Comment: Thank you !! You seem to be quite good at chaining...I am learning